# "No instance for" error

Tags: haskell, ghci

Following an example in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Beginning

```
Prelude> let abs x = if x < 0 then -x else x
Prelude> abs 5
5
Prelude> abs -3

<interactive>:1:6:
    No instance for (Num (a0 -> a0))
      arising from the literal `3'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (a0 -> a0))
    In the second argument of `(-)', namely `3'
    In the expression: abs - 3
    In an equation for `it': it = abs - 3
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The explanation of the error message, just for future reference: `a0 -> a0` is the type of `abs`. (Type `:t abs` in your ghci to see it.) The error message is saying that this type `a0 -> a0` is not an instance of the type class `Num`, as only `Num`s can be subtracted from each other, and in any case the `3` means that the first argument must be of some type in `Num`. (In ghci type `:t (-)` and `:t 3` to see what's going on.) The line "in the second argument of \`(-)', namely \`3'" is most revealing: it shows that `-` is being treated as an infix operator with *two* arguments, not unary minus.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Haskell thinks you're trying to subtract `3` from `abs`, and is complaining that `abs` is not a number. You need to add parenthesis when using the unary negation operator:

```
abs (-3)
```

Comment: Cheers. The wikibooks documentation seems to be incoreect in several places.

Answer (score 5):

The interpreter thinks you mean `abs - 3` not `abs (-3)`. You need brackets to disambiguate the code and make sure it's clear that you intend to use the unary "-" function, not the subtraction operator.