# Mapping over a list in Haskell: Non-type variable argument in constraint

Tags: haskell, mapping

```
let fun1  = (+3)
let fun2  = (-3)
let range = [1,2,3,3]
let a = map fun1 range
let b = map fun2 a
```

This gives me an error:

> Non-type variable argument in the constraint: Num (a -> b)

The static nature of Haskell really gives me headaches...

Comment: Because Haskell is static, you can also check the type in GHCi. Notice that `:t fun2` gives you just a number - not a function. It turns out `-` is special (it is the only special operator in the language). `(-3)` is sugar for `negate 3`.

Comment: Another relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6224212/no-instance-for-error

Comment: A general comment on the attitude displayed here: [you don't know what's wrong, so how do you know it is the static nature of Haskell that is giving you this headache](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#symptoms)?

Comment: @DanielWagner It's the error message that really shows the static nature. In a dynamic language it would probably result in an error message like "Tried to call a non-function", which would be much more self-explanatory, instead of speaking of constraints and "non-type variable arguments".

Comment: @hgiesel The reason the error message is so terrible combines many parts of Haskell's nature -- chiefly its polymorphism, section syntax, and a small wart around number literal syntax -- but not really its statically-typed nature. Compare e.g. the error from `map True [1,2,3]`, which does essentially say "tried to call a non-function".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it is more the syntax than the type system here that gives you a headache. That's because `(-3)` actually is the number "*minus three*":

```
fun2 :: Num a => a
```

So the problem is you do not really provide a function, but more a constant.

You could for instance solve it by writing:

```
let fun2 = \x -> x-3
```

or:

```
let fun2 = (+) (-3)
```

> The static nature of Haskell really gives me headaches...

Actually I sleep a lot better when programs are written in Haskell since in dynamically typed languages you often have "*werewolf-days*": days where all goes wrong.

Comment: The `Prelude` function `subtract` was added precisely to achieve what `(-3)` would be if it were a section. One can `map (subtract 3) xs` for instance.